# Getting the entire selected value from combobox using PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a combobox which contains values that some of them contains spaces.
The combobox is populated dynamically from mysql db.

```
public function getSizeList(){
        $query = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT size_range FROM sizes ORDER BY size_range");              
        $prefix = "<select name='size_range'required>                                                       
                    <option selected disabled value=''>Select a Size</option>";
        $body ="";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $size_range = $row['size_range'];
            $body .= "<option value=" . $size_range . ">$size_range</option>";
        }
        $suffix="</select>";

        return $prefix . $body . $suffix;
    }
```

This function returns a combobox with following values:

```
index 0: Select a Size // disabled
index 1: 0cm to 50cm
index 2: 51cm to 100cm
index 3: greater than 100cm
```

The problem is when clicking on submit button to save the selected value in database, I am getting only the first word of the selected value.
For example, selecting the second item in the combobox returns **0cm** instead of **0cm to 50cm**

I am using: **$_POST['size_range']** to get the value.

How can I get the entire value using PHP?

Comment: Yury nailed it.   There were no quotes around the strings so your html looked like this `<option value=51cm to 100cm>51cm to 100cm</option>`  <--- notice anything wrong.   If you right-click view-source, it would have revealed this :)

Comment: @KraangPrime, I am totally new in this stuff, good to know about the view source, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose each option's value in double quotes:

```
$body .= "<option value=\"" . $size_range . "\">$size_range</option>";
```

Note that you need to escape the quotes here, since you use the same quotes in PHP.

Comment: Good eye.  I totally overlooked that :)    Upvoted !